# Nqueens implementation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried to implement the **N- Queens problem** using javascript and executing it using the node **REPL** js interpreter.
Here are the two main functions that I've used:

```
 function isSafe( board, row, column){

 //To check for a queen in the same row to the left
 for (i=0;i<column;i++)
  if(board[row][i])
   return false;
 //To check for a queen diagonally below to the left
 for ( i=0 , j=0 ; i<row , j< column; i++ , j++)
  if (board[i][j])
   return false;
 //To check for a queen diagonally above to the left.
 for (i=board[0].length-1 , j=0 ; i> row ,  j<column; i-- ,j++)
  if (board[i][j])
   return false;
 //Otherwise the queen can be placed
  return true;
}
```

and
     function NQUtil(board, column){

```
 if(column==board[0].length-1)
 {
    for(i=0;i<board.length ; i++)
        console.log(board[i]);
    return true;
 }
for ( i =0 ; i< board[0].length;i++){
if(isSafe(board,i,column))  
    board[i][column]=1;
NQUtil(board, column+1);    
board[i][column]=0;
return false;
 }
}
```

Here's my error when I pass a board matrix (board,0) to the NQUtil function:

```
board[i][column]=0;
            ^

TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined
```

When I pass (Array(board),column) to every recursive call NQUtil to overcome the 'undefined' problem I get this:

```
function isSafe( board, row, column){
           ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at isSafe (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:2:16)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:30:5)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
at NQUtil (/home/vivek/nqueens.js:32:2)
```

Passing a 4x4 array of zeros-- an unoccupied chessboard, I am not able to find out where exactly the call stack is overflowing . Please help me.
Thanks,
Vivek Vasudevan.

Update: Here's my function to create an array of zeros:

```
 function zeros(dimensions) {
 var array = new Array(dimensions[0]);
 for(var i =0; i<dimensions[0]; i++)
  array[i]=new Array(dimensions[1]);
 for(var i=0;i<dimensions[0];i++)
  for(var j=0;j<dimensions[1];j++)
   array[i][j]=0    
 return array;
 }
```

An these are the calls to the functions:

```
 board=zeros([4,4]);

 NQUtil(board , 0);
```

Comment: `board[i]` is undefined. Have you set all `board[i]` to an empty array before?

Comment: Yes, a 4x4 array of zeros

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That error `Cannot set property '2' of undefined` happened to me too because the implementation of the base case was wrong. I post the answer for future reference.

```js
// queeen can move all 4 directions and diagonally.
// each queen has to be in different column, row, positive diagonal and negative diagonal
// pattern for negative diagonal. we are increasing row and col values by 1. r-c stays constant
// pattern for positive diagonal. r+c stays constant

var solveNQueens = function (n) {
  const res = [];
  const posDiagonal = new Set();
  const negDiagonal = new Set();
  const cols = new Set();
  // we fill it with something so we could call map().
  let board = Array(n)
    .fill(0)
    .map(() => Array(n).fill("."));

  const dfs = (r) => {
    if (r === n) {
      const copiedBoard = board.map((row) => row.join(""));
      res.push(copiedBoard);
      return;
    }
    for (let c = 0; c < n; c++) {
      if (cols.has(c) || negDiagonal.has(r - c) || posDiagonal.has(r + c)) {
        continue;
      }
      board[r][c] = "Q";
      posDiagonal.add(r + c);
      negDiagonal.add(r - c);
      cols.add(c);
      dfs(r + 1);
      // After you found one solution, before starting second solution, you need to reset the board and sets
      board[r][c] = ".";
      posDiagonal.delete(r + c);
      negDiagonal.delete(r - c);
      cols.delete(c);
    }
  };
  dfs(0);
  return res;
};
```